# Why is my on load Bootstrap modal backdrop loading after the rest of the page content?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog, onload

My Bootstrap modal loads first on a page with this code:

```
$(window).load(function(){
$('#myModal').modal('show');
});
```

The problem is that the modal backdrop and it's css animation loads after the whole page is loaded and therefore a bit delayed after the modal load. How do I avoid this and make the backdrop load right after the modal and not wait for the entire page??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`window.onload` waits for all the images to load. Use document ready

```
$(function(){
    $('#myModal').modal('show');
});
```

or delete the hide class and forget about the JavaScript